# Install Receiver's onReceiver never called

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a custom receiver that handles INSTALL_REFERRER intents when the application is installed. It was called once or twice during testing but now doesn't get called at all. I am using an emulator for testing and have gone through the instructions in [this test documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns#prepare) to broadcast an install intent to the emulator. I have also made sure that I hooked up my Android SDK ADB to the emulator, so it should be receiving the broadcasts. In the terminal, it says that my broadcast succeeded, however when I launch the app from the a fresh install the onReceive is never called.

Here the skeleton of my Receiver:

```
public class CustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        //do stuff
        //log stuff
    }
}
```

And here is my manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name="path.to.CustomReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I've tried starting with a new emulator to make sure it wasn't blacklisting the calls, and looked through all the documentation and posts about this that I could find, but nothing seems to work. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

The docs you refer to are from 2013. More recent docs suggest using an [InstallReferrerReceiver](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/InstallReferrerReceiver), which is specifically designed to handle that intent:

> The Google Play com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER Intent is broadcast when an app is installed from the Google Play Store. [InstallReferrerReceiver] listens for that Intent, passing the install referrer data to GTM for Mobile Apps and Google Analytics.